Prepend Text in Crispy Forms - Django
I have a form that works generally as expected, but I am trying to prepend some text on one of the fields to make it more user-friendly. In this case, all entries in the "RFP Control Number" field should start with "RFP-" so I want to use crispy forms to prepend that text. I have followed the setup in the crispy forms documentation to the best of my ability, but am not having any luck getting the prepended text to show up. Any ideas?
The documentation is linked below:
https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html
And a simplified version of my form is included below as well.
class ProposalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Proposal
        fields = [
            'organization', 'rfp_control_number',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProposalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
    
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'organization',
            PrependedText('rfp_control_number', 'RFP-'),
            Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary'),
        )

I tried the few different syntaxes listed in the documentation website included in my post to no avail. I have looked online for articles and watched YouTube videos about Crispy Forms, but I have not found anything that covers this directly. This is a simplified version of my form to test on.

def __init__(self, instance=None, data={}, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance and not data.get('{field name}'): data[{field name}] = 'RFP-'
    super().__init__(data=data, instance=instance, *args, **kwargs)


When I try that exact code (swapping in the field name), it doesn't seem to work for me, but I do appreciate you pointing me towards the initial value. That will sort of handle what I am working for, at least in the short term. Longer term, I would like to have the text I am trying to prepend not be editable, like the example they show in the crispy forms documentation using prepended @ for the username. Thank you for the help!

Would you like to try changing initial to data?

I am not sure what you mean, can you explain?
Here is what I have currently, and I paired this with some JS that restores the "RFP-" to the beginning of the field if it is edited. Not optimal, but it's working:
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProposalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
    
    self.fields['rfp_control_number'].initial = 'RFP-'


Not sure how to get that to format properly here in the comment, sorry ^

i edited answer. please check. maybe it works in create new object.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

This doesn't seem to be handling it either, and isn't using the crispy forms functionality. For now, I will just plan to stick with using initial, plus JS to ensure those values don't get deleted. Thanks again for the help!
